# User defined function returning incorrect value in Pycharm but not IDLE

Tags: python, pycharm, user-defined-functions, python-idle

i'm very new to programing and have run into something I just can't figure out!
I have a user defined function which is supposed to calculate a percentage:

```
def test_score(num_correct, total):
    temp_value = num_correct / total
    return temp_value*100

a = 12
b = 20
print(test_score(a, b))
```

By my calculations the program should be returning the value 60, and it does so when the code is entered into IDLE. However, when entered into Pycharm the code is returning the value 0.

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: They will probably be using different versions of Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably down to different Python versions as pointed out in the comments.

Python2:

```
12 / 20 -> 0  (default for integers)
12 * 1.0 / 20 -> 0.6  (if float is involved)
```

Python3:

```
12 / 20 -> 0.6  (default for integers)
12 // 20 -> 0  (floor division)
```

See the docs on [division](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/division.html) and [floor division](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html).
In Pycharm, you can set the Python version under `settings -> project -> project interpreter` (or similar, depending on version and plattform).

Comment: Excellent, when num_correct and total are converted to floats within the function the correct answer is received.